# KeyBinding two commands (one in the VM and one in the View) to one key

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding, mvvm

I have a text box that looks like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Stuff, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding Path=LoadStuffCommand}" />
        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="SelectAll"  />
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

When it runs only the SelectAll command is run.  However, if I take out the SelectAll line then the LoadStuffCommand runs fine.

Clearly it is replacing the command with the next one (last one wins).  But I need a way to both run my command and select all the text in the TextBox too.

Normally, I would just make another command that fires both my commands.  But one of these is in my ViewModel and one is in my View.  How can I make a command that fires both?  (Is there a way to make a command in XAML?)

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601270/can-i-call-a-command-inside-a-command

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with [an aggregator](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25808/Aggregating-WPF-Commands-with-CommandGroup). Basically, group the commands into an object that calls them in sequence, and bind to the object as if its one command.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  However, that example uses commands that are custom rolled (so they have an "Instance" property) or are application level commands.  I am just using a DelegateCommand on my ViewModel or the SelectAll command on my TextBox.  Rolling my own command class for this seems like it is the wrong approach.

Comment: DelegateCommands implement Icommand. You should be able to use this solution without changing anything. Or roll your own, using this model. Its very simple.